# How does one "mirror" the bullets of an unordered list?

Tags: jquery, html, css

It was hard to phrase this question.

I'll assume most of you are aware that a normal unordered list has the bullets on the left side. I'd like to know if it's possible to get these bullets on the right side (jquery solutions are fine).

To go into detail a bit, assume that:

1. There are 2 lists I want to display side-by-side : `foo` and `bar`.
2. The text alignment of the `bar` list should to the right.
3. The bullets of the `bar` list should be on the opposing side.

P.S. Since I think someone will utter, "Why? Why in the name of all that is logical would you want to do such a thing?" My humble but illogical code-monkeying self must confess that it's a bit bored of the "norm". ;)

Edit:

The use of `dir='rtl'` will not work for my case as it results in undesired effects due to me only wanting the bullet reversed, not the sentence as well.

Comment: `dir='rtf'` will be fine if you just reverse the sentence.

Comment: Bizarre how many times people have put `dir='rtf'` on this page.  Copy-pasting or just group typo? ;)

Comment: @bmoeskau: I believe we are the unfortunate owners of disobedient keyboards. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use `dir='rtl'`, I think there's no good solution really. You could use CSS to disable the default list bullets and position a background image instead as a workaround. Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>First point. </td><td> <li> </li></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Second point. </td><td> <li> </li></td></tr>
</table>
```

Which is a nasty looking workaround, but does do what you want. Tables for layout is obviously undesirable, but here I think a CSS equivalent in terms of positioning and variable-height alignment would be quite a lot more complex.

Comment: I would recommend disabling the bullets and mocking an image in the padding. At the very least it leaves you with the ul/li structure in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<ul dir='rtl'>...</ul>`.

The `dir='rtf'` snippet tells the browser that the text should be read right-to-left ("direction: right-to-left").

Edit: See comments! This shouldn't be used for left-to-right languages!

Comment: @gov 'dir' stands for direction check http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/dirlang.html#adef-dir

Comment: @peakit , thanks may i know how to add questions as favorites and retreive the same...

Comment: @Closure Cowboy: Well that was quick. :) How's cross-browser support?

Comment: It works in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE8, and perhaps earlier versions of IE, but I can't test using those...

Comment: @Closure Cowboy: After some testing it seems that while it that attribute does result in a mirrored bulleted list, it does more as well which results in unwanted effects.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with css using the direction attribute. Just do `direction:rtl`.

The complete picture:

```
<ul style="float:left">
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
<ul style="direction:rtl;float:right;">
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

http://startwithabreak.com/misc/test.html

Comment: If you replace `Foo` and `Bar` with completely sentences, you'll notice an undesired effect (as Closure Cowboy noticed).

Comment: Eh, how often do you need periods in lists anyway.